# Where to handle fatal error caused by phone call interrupt?

Tags: ios, swift

```
2017-05-04 19:31:44.298638 App[789:140790] [aurioc] 889: failed: '!pla' (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>)
    2017-05-04 19:31:44.315019 App[789:140790] [aurioc] 889: failed: '!pla' (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>)
    2017-05-04 19:31:44.319277 App[789:140790] [central] 54:   ERROR:    [0x1a651fc40] >avae> AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:2515: PerformCommand: error 561015905
    2017-05-04 19:31:44.322203 App[789:140790] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error 561015905'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x1816721c0 0x1800ac55c 0x181672094 0x19ad5478c 0x19ad68170 0x19ad68e58 0x19add63a0 0x19add56b0 0x19add5640 0x1914f8440 0x1914dceb8 0x18160c22c 0x18160b930 0x18160b6ac 0x18167ab9c 0x18154dbf4 0x18205762c 0x187534f84 0x18775aa38 0x187768fdc 0x1877545e0 0x187754264 0x187a85ba4 0x1831ebb8c 0x1832198bc 0x183219728 0x183219ad0 0x181620278 0x18161fbc0 0x18161d7c0 0x18154c048 0x182fd2198 0x1875382fc 0x187533034 0x100064b74 0x1805305b8)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

When running my app which does not include any audio features at all, if I get a phone call during, this error outputs, and my app crashes.

I am not sure where to handle phone interrupts like this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: What if you press the home button and the app goes to background? Does it work fine then? Because basically when you get a call iOS puts your app into background and brings the Phone app into foreground. You get notified via `applicationWillResignActive` so it shouldn't just crash.

Comment: When I press home button it works fine (no errors)...then I can re enter the app in the state I left it. I was having a look at the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods, and I cant tell if one of them suits the event of a phone call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found the solution. Turns out it is a bug that apple plans to fix on next realise. It is because I am using scenekit, which uses an audio engine which must be properly initlized.

```
sceneView.audioEngine.mainMixerNode.outputVolume = 0.0;
```

activates it.